# C++ docking windows

Tags: c++, windows, dock

is there any way to dock two windows(like Winamp does with panels), but one window is from my application(WinApi) and second is from other(not connected with my app) application? So if I move window from other app my window will "glue" with it and move same direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fairly easy. Use `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, otherHWND)` to get the `WM_MOVE` message that will be generated whenever `otherHWND` moves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible in C++ because I program in C# but what you could try is:

Make 2 panels.
Dock panel2 to the bottom.
dock panel1 to fill.
Place a splitter above panel2 so it can be resized.

I've used this solution before and it worked pretty well :).